# How deploy React app locally only in my PC?

Tags: reactjs, localhost, web-deployment

I’m working on a project. In this project, I'm creating a React user interfaces to enter data. So now, I only can run the React project with `npm start`. That mean I need code to run the project

Is there any way to deploy my project locally? I mean, I need a way to run the React project without use of code. I need to deploy only on my local PC.

Comment: Do you mean you want to start your project automatically when your system boots?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Yes, Do u have any solution sir !

Comment: You can install a web server on your local machine, [apache](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-apache#1-overview) or [nginx](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-and-configure-nginx#1-overview) and deploy i.e. copy / paste your bundle (output of `npm run build`) files and you can access it in your browser at `http://localhost`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this following:

1. Build your react project
2. Use server and visit your url. ex: localhost:8887

You can use `Web Server for Chrome` for server.

Comment: I did that, But when the code is not there, that is not working!!! I want a method to deploy my react app locally. When we use heroku or something to deploy the app, it is accessible by anyone who has the link. I want only to deploy project locally. (In my PC)

Comment: Follow another answer

Answer (score 0):

Consider checkbox:

[image: Reference Image]

If you check those checkboxes, others can access your site.